# Present tense in Flashback story for something that is still true now?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

I'm wondering whether I should use the present tense for a descriptive statement but in a past context. For example:

> (1) I went to the zoo and saw a giraffe last week.
>
> (2) A giraffe **is** a mammal with long neck.
>
> (3) It **is** the first time I **see** that animal with my own eyes.

Statement (2) is a description of a giraffe in general, not the specific one in the zoo, so is it correct to use *is*?

Statement (3) is an event that is still true now, so should I use *is* and *see*?

I'm not native speaker so forgive me if the question is very obvious to others.

Comment: (2) needs an article in front of *giraffe*. Either *a* or *the* would work, but you shouldn't leave it without an article.

Comment: @ws2 so the correct statement is "A giraffe is a mammal..."?

Comment: Yes. You could also say *The giraffe is a mammal* (meaning giraffes in general). Or *Giraffes are mammals*. Either of those would be idiomatic. But NOT *Giraffe is a mammal*.

Comment: The first *is* is correct. The last sentence ought to be *It **was** the first time I **had seen** that animal with my own eyes.*

Comment: @Anonym it sounds weird with past perfect, is there a reason? Thanks

Comment: @DarcCode I'll admit that I can't give the reason off the top of my head. The best reasoning that I can give is that, if the sentence were in the present tense, it would read *It **is** the first time I **have seen** that animal with my own eyes.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verb agreement for something that was discussed in the past, while the issue still exists in the present](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72719/verb-agreement-for-something-that-was-discussed-in-the-past-while-the-issue-sti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving a descriptive account of a past event, despite the facts still being true, it would be advisable to use the past tense of verbs. Your 2nd statement is fine, as you're presenting someone with the character of a Giraffe, in case they don't know about the animal but after that the account relates back to the past event i.e your experience at the zoo. You **saw** the animal with your own eyes and it **was** the first time that you had this experience

Comment: Wait, should I say "Appreciated it!"?

Comment: Appreciate it, is correct, you're welcome.